# Python - Why is this data being written to file incorrectly?

Tags: python, web-scraping

Only the first result is being written to a csv, with one letter of the url per row.  This is instead of all urls being written, one per row.

What am I not doing right in the last section of this code that is causing the cvs to be written only with one of the results instead of all of them?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

def grab_listings():
    url = ("http://www.gym-directory.com/listing-category/gyms-fitness-centres/")
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    l_area = soup.find("div", {"class":"wlt_search_results"})
    for elem in l_area.findAll("a", {"class":"frame"}):
        return elem["href"]

    url = ("http://www.gym-directory.com/listing-category/gyms-fitness-centres/page/2/")
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    l_area = soup.find("div", {"class":"wlt_search_results"})
    for elem in l_area.findAll("a", {"class":"frame"}):
        return elem["href"]

    url = ("http://www.gym-directory.com/listing-category/gyms-fitness-centres/page/3/")
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    l_area = soup.find("div", {"class":"wlt_search_results"})
    for elem in l_area.findAll("a", {"class":"frame"}):
        return elem["href"]

    url = ("http://www.gym-directory.com/listing-category/gyms-fitness-centres/page/4/")
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    l_area = soup.find("div", {"class":"wlt_search_results"})
    for elem in l_area.findAll("a", {"class":"frame"}):
        return elem["href"]

    url = ("http://www.gym-directory.com/listing-category/gyms-fitness-centres/page/5/")
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    l_area = soup.find("div", {"class":"wlt_search_results"})
    for elem in l_area.findAll("a", {"class":"frame"}):
        return elem["href"]

    url = ("http://www.gym-directory.com/listing-category/gyms-fitness-centres/page/6/")
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    l_area = soup.find("div", {"class":"wlt_search_results"})
    for elem in l_area.findAll("a", {"class":"frame"}):
        return elem["href"]

    url = ("http://www.gym-directory.com/listing-category/gyms-fitness-centres/page/7/")
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    l_area = soup.find("div", {"class":"wlt_search_results"})
    for elem in l_area.findAll("a", {"class":"frame"}):
        return elem["href"]

    url = ("http://www.gym-directory.com/listing-category/gyms-fitness-centres/page/8/")
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    l_area = soup.find("div", {"class":"wlt_search_results"})
    for elem in l_area.findAll("a", {"class":"frame"}):
        return elem["href"]

    url = ("http://www.gym-directory.com/listing-category/gyms-fitness-centres/page/9/")
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    l_area = soup.find("div", {"class":"wlt_search_results"})
    for elem in l_area.findAll("a", {"class":"frame"}):
        return elem["href"]

l = grab_listings()


with open ("gyms.csv", "wb") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        for row in l:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: you will not get more data after first return..

Comment: Your function stops executing the moment you first return anything, in the first loop

Comment: You have two problems: 1. `return` can only happen once per function (you may want to read up on generators, and `yield`); and 2. given that, you're therefore iterating over *a single string* and passing each character to `writerow`. The result is inevitable.

Comment: Also, those 9 almost identical sections of `grab_listings` could be handled by a single section in a simple loop. Your code would be easier to read & maintain if you [didn't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplified:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


def grab_listings():
    for i in range(0, 5):
        url = "http://www.gym-directory.com/listing-category/gyms-fitness-centres/page/{}/"

        r = requests.get(url.format(i + 1))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        l_area = soup.find("div", {"class": "wlt_search_results"})

        for elem in l_area.findAll("a", {"class": "frame"}):
            yield elem["href"]

l = grab_listings()


with open("gyms.csv", "w") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for row in l:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: This is certainly a significant improvement on the code, but I suspect this would be more useful to the OP if you **explained what you've changed, and why**.

Comment: This code doesn't do the same as the original one.. you are right that it could be simplified, but the first case does not have a page appended and all the other ones go from 2 till 9 and not from 1 till 5 –  Salo 51 mins ago

Comment: Thanks for the answer Fanti.  I've actually used your method because it displays each url on a row, which is what I was looking for.  As mentioned above though, each letter is separated by a comma.
Can you show me how to amend your code so that the results are not broken by a comma each letter?

Comment: @McLeodx `writerow` expects an iterable - you give it a string, so it iterates over the characters. If you only want one thing on each row, *why are you using `csv`*?!

Comment: In all honesty Jon I've been working from an example that uses csv, so trying to learn a number of different things relating to this at once.. I hadn't got to whether or not to use csv yet, but obviously it's not the best option here then?

Answer (score 1):

So I refactored your code a bit and i think it should work as you would expect it now:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


def grab_listings(page_idx):
    ret = []
    url = ("http://www.gym-directory.com/listing-category/gyms-fitness-centres/"
           "page/{}/").format(page_idx) # the index of the page will be inserted here
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    l_area = soup.find("div", {"class": "wlt_search_results"})
    for elem in l_area.findAll("a", {"class": "frame"}):
        # be sure to add all your results to a list and return it,
        # if you return here then you will only get the first result
        ret.append(elem["href"])
    return ret


def main():
    l = [] # this will be a list of lists
    # call the function 9 times here with idx from 1 till 9
    for page_idx in range(1, 10):
        l.append(grab_listings(page_idx))
    print l

    with open("gyms.csv", "wb") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for row in l:
            # be sure that your row is a list here, if it is only
            # a string all characters will be seperated by a comma.
            writer.writerow(row)

# for writing each URL in one line separated by commas at the end 
#    with open("gyms.csv", "wb") as f:
#        for row in l:
#            string_to_write = ',\n'.join(row)
#            f.write(string_to_write)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I added some comments to the code and hope it is explanatory enough. If not just ask :)

Comment: Thanks Salo, and the explanations are particularly helpful!  When I'm using this code though it's creating a cvs with 9 rows, and data is stored like <url>,<url>,<url> with one row of urls per page.
How would this be amended so that each row had one url? (i.e. 96 rows)

Comment: You're welcome @McLeodx. This is even easier as you don't need to use the csv module. You could alter the code to give a one dimensional list and the join it. With the existing code it is possible to replace the open part like in the updated answer.